# how to filter date mm/dd/yyyy from passing any number from text input in angular 10 with primeng

Tags: angular, primeng, angular10, primeng-turbotable

I did use primeng filter on turbo table but its not working with date which is having format "mm/dd/yyyy".

```
                   *ngIf="col.field === 'abc'"
                   pInputText
                   type="text"
                   (input)="
                     dt.filter(
                       $event.target.value,
                       'abc',
                       'contains'
                     )
                   "
                   class="p-column-filter"
                 />
```

but it only works with number if I type in text box if I am entering "/" then it doesnt work.

I need a filter who can show result as per matching data from input and input is "07/02/2019 01:30:00"

its mm/dd/yyyy format

Could anyone help me into this?

Is there another way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can use the p-calendar element instead of an input: [Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2.8-lts/#/calendar). It would be like this:

```
<p-calendar [ngModel]="value"  dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" showTime="true" hourFormat="12" (ngModelChange)="dateChange($event)">
</p-calendar>
```

And in your typescript code, you add:

```
dateChange($event) {
    if ($event) {
      //You call method filter
      dt.filter($event.target.value,'abc','contains')
    }
  }
```

I hope it helps you. Greetings!

Comment: thanks... but the requirement is for the input text :)

Comment: Oh!. I thought you could use it because the calendar component is an input component to select dates. I'm sorry. I hope you find a solution!! Maybe, this link can help you: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2.8-lts/#/table/filter

Comment: actually from server response the date format was different and I was changing the date format in order to show on ui so it works.

Comment: Fantastic! Congratulations! Greetings and have a good afternoon! And I'm sorry for not being helpful @Sum

Answer (score 0):

I have added a function `(onSelect)="filterByDate($event, dt2)"`, here i passed selected date and table.

```
<p-columnFilter type="date" field="processedDate" display="menu">
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-filter="filterCallback">
        <p-calendar dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" (onSelect)="filterByDate($event, dt2)"></p-calendar>
    </ng-template>
</p-columnFilter
```

component.js file contains below implemenation

```
filterByDate(event: any, table: any) {
    let formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(event, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    table.filterGlobal(formattedDate, 'customContains');
}
```

Here I have implemented `customContains` filter, which is similar to `contains` filter;
It works for both globalfilter and datefilter;